# Why I can't process My hadoop program next?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

everybody!
I have a program about hadoop in eclipse, and the source code is:

```
public class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for(IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] oargs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if(oargs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: word count <in> <out>");
        }
        System.out.println("input:  "+oargs[0]);
        System.out.println("output: "+oargs[1]);
        Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(oargs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(oargs[1]));
        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.println("start ...");
        boolean flag = job.waitForCompletion(true);
            System.out.println(flag);
        System.out.println("end ...");
        System.out.println("==============================");
    }
}
```

and the result is, please see the log:

```
rory@0303 /cygdrive/f/develop/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3
$ ./bin/hadoop jar ./jar/wordcount.jar /tmp/input /tmp/output
input:  /tmp/input
output: /tmp/output
==============================
start ...
12/07/25 14:59:17 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/07/25 14:59:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/07/25 14:59:17 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/07/25 14:59:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201207251447_0001
12/07/25 14:59:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

the log is not go on and stop there forever. why?

I am running the code in local mode, by cygwin software in windows xp system.

Comment: What is the meaning of "do it next"? What do you expect it should do? Normally you have to wait until your cluster processes this job and returns back to you, that's the meaning of `waitForCompletion`. If your job was not successful you are existing your JVM.

Comment: Are you able to post the task logs for either of the 2 maps tasks that should be running? You can access these via the job tracker web ui, http://localhost:50030

Answer (score 0):

@ Rory, as Thomas have asked, could you be more specific on **"do it next"**? Is this the entire stack trace that you have got on the screen? Do you mean that you have compiled it once and then got the result and not able to run it again? Have you specified the correct input arguments ie the **input and output directories** for your program on eclipse IDE?

In case you mean that you are not able to run the program again for the second time, may be you have not specified a different output directory. But I guess that is not the case after seeing the Stack Trace.

Comment: Thanks Arun, I mean is when my code debug into `job.waitForCompletion(true)`, my code do not go on and stop there forever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you're asking why you never see the `end ====================` println portion, then check your code:

```
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
System.out.println("end ...");
System.out.println("==============================");
```

You're wrapping the `job.waitForCompletion(true)` call with a `System.exit`, hence the JVM will terminate before the final two System.out's can execute.

**EDIT**

The log appender / logger messages here are a clue that any other exceptions are probably being swallowed. You should amend the signature of your code to utilize the ToolRunner utility:

```
public class WordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);  
  }

  public int run(String args[]) {
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: word count <in> <out>");
    }
    System.out.println("input:  "+args[0]);
    System.out.println("output: "+args[1]);
    Job job = new Job(getConf(), "word count");
    Configuration conf = job.getConf();

    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println("start ...");
    int result = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    System.out.println("end ...");
    System.out.println("==============================");

    return results
  }
}
```

And you should use the $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop script to submit your job to the cluster (as follows, you'll need to substitute the name of your jar and fully qualified name of the WordCount class):

```
#> hadoop jar wordcount.jar WordCount input output
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I want to see " end ==================== " println, But my problem is not " System.exit ", When my code debug into " job.waitForCompletion(true) ", my code is not go on.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I want to see `end ==================== `println, But my problem is not due to `System.exit`, When my code debug into `job.waitForCompletion(true)` , my code is not go on and stop there forever

Comment: Does your job even submit? The warning messages look suspicious - you shoulnd't be seeing the one about appenders / loggers

Comment: See my edits for some suggestions - are you running in psuedo, distirbuted or local mode?

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am running in local mode, by cygwin software in windows xp system. by your suggestions, I print my log to you! please see the follow comments, thanks!

Comment: `rory@0303 /cygdrive/f/develop/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3`

Comment: `$ ./bin/hadoop jar ./jar/wordcount.jar /tmp/input /tmp/output`

Comment: `==============================`

Comment: `start ...`  `12/07/25 14:59:17 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2`

Comment: `12/07/25 14:59:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

Comment: `12/07/25 14:59:17 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded`

Comment: `12/07/25 14:59:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201207251447_0001`

Comment: `12/07/25 14:59:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%`